# what is the of exact original/source text of "Life is really simple, but we insist on making it complicated"

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

I was browsing http://www.brainyquote.com/ website and found that the top one quote on hot topic "life" is an quote from Confucius(http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/topics/topic_life.html):

"Life is really simple, but we insist on making it complicated"

I do read part of *The Analects of Confucius* however I doesn't remember any quote with similar meaning. what is the exact original/source text of quote above? How should I translate it to Chinese? I have tried google translation but only get Vernacular Chinese sentence which of course could not be the original one.

Answer (score 2):

On the [wikipedia page for Confucius](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Confucius), in the "Misattributed" section, you can find this quote:

> Life is really simple, but we insist on making it complicated.
>
> Attributed on the internet but not found in print prior to an attribution in Aero Digest, 1949, p. 115

Comment: Some source shows it's actually from 《新唐书·陆象先传》： "天下本无事，庸人扰之为烦耳。" a.k.a the well-known saying "世上本无事，庸人自扰之。"

Comment: @Stan I think that comment should be an answer.

Comment: @KWeiss Haven't done enough search work. Maybe Confucius had said something similar. So I didn't put it as an answer.